# How do i weight the whole mesh to a single bone?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I am currently modeling a ladybug and trying to put an armature in it. The ladybug's legs are segmented and i am planning to set 1 piece of bone to every single segments.

The problem is painting the weight often giving me half weighted result. What i want is a way to select an element of mesh using the L key, and assign that whole selection to a particular bone. Is there a way that is similar to what i was trying to do? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Select your mesh, then select your armature using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose `With Empty Groups`
3. Select your mesh enter Edit Mode then select the vertices/faces you want to be part of a particular bone and then select the bone you want them to be part of from the vertex group panel and hit <kbd>Assign</kbd> as shown below. 
   [image]

Then these vertices will be part of this bone.
[image]